# How to use Angular components like aspx user controls

Tags: angular

I spent a lot of year in the older Asp.Net web forms world, where they had (in my opinion) a wonderful concept called *User Controls*.

Write a user control and place it *anywhere* in your website, and to use it in a web form, ***you only needed to add ONE line of code in your web form to access the user control***, the Register tag:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cmpy" TagName="Company" Src="~/Controls/Company.ascx" %>
```

And presto, you have complete access to the user control. You can register the control on as many pages as you wish. What could be more simpler or intuitive?

I believe that the web form User Control equivalent in Angular is the Component. However the transition for me to the Angular world has been frustrating because there are certain things I simply am not 'getting'. For example, right now I am trying to figure out how to use an Angular Component like a User Control. That is, I want to share code.

If I have a Component called ShareMe, how can I use that component within more than one component? That is my fundamental question for this post.

For example, let's say I have components A, B, C.

An Angular component can only be declared in one module, correct? So who gets to declare ShareMe? Would it be in app.module? Or do I have to create a completely new module called ShareMe.module.ts and declare it there, for the sole purpose of being able to share the component?

Do I also need a module for each of the components A, B, and C in order to be able to use ShareMe? If so what goes into those modules to accomplish that?

How does app.module.ts fit into all of this?

What I want to do seems sensible, but I have not been able to find anything on line to help me accomplish the goal of easily and intuitively sharing code in Angular. Can anyone help? Thanks, BB

Comment: If the selector of share me is `share-me` to render it you just add `<share-me></share-me>`. This is all [covered in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview#creating-a-component-manually)

Comment: Webforms is a 20 year old technology, time to move on. Things don't work like that anymore

Comment: Liam: 1)There is a sentence where I state the fundamental question. Where did I ask someone to explain all of Angular? 2) No, what I want to do is not covered in the link you provided. 3) I also stated that I am working in Angular, where did I say I was still working in Web Forms? I was making an analogy to Web Forms. But the fact is that what I could do twenty years ago with one line of code in Web Forms cannot be done with one line of code in Angular. You'd think Angular could at least match that. Things *should* work like that : newer should be easier or at least not more convoluted.

Comment: @BarnumBailey, generally in Angular you hase a differents modules related all the components about it (e.g. module client.module with a client-detail.component and client-list.component) and a module utils (e.g. util.module with special-list.component,search.component,date-selected.component,numbered.pipe...). the "key" is that the module.util use "export" so all the components and pipes are accesible in all the modules you import this util.module. take a look to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly so I will divide the answers into two:

1. The logic for "modules" is for lazy loading, meaning that we don't want to render components if they are not going to be used on the said page, that would just be waste of memory. So we end up creation context specific modules where that module injects all of the required components, you will need to write a router to this and look into writing these said "lazy loading" logic for angular. By doing so you will be able to write components where they are "shared" so it will allow to use this "shared" module across multiple modules. Best I can think of is angulars official documentation but I strongly suggest watching videos and other blogs to have a strong foundation for this logic. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
2. It sounds like to me that you are looking for something called "service" or a more basic version of it "pipe".
   A service would be very similar to what a "Controller - service" is to .NET. The thing about Angular service is that you don't build any visual aspects to it, so it is just logic, a component has visual aspect to it (you can avoid writing HTML - Css but you get the point). You can inject that said service to your components constructor and access all of their methods without having to re-write them.

Official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

A blog I've found that I think does a good job: https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/angular-tutorial/angular-service